# Form GET serialized data different on new server

Tags: php, forms, get

I had set up a demo web app on my personal server. When a user submits the info on the form, the array of info is sent through the form. It worked fine on my server. When I moved it to a new server, it no longer sends the correct information. I noticed the string is slightly different. Is there some sort of setting I need to change on the new server?

For both sites, I chose February and submitted the form.

The string that gets passed on the old server:

```
months=a%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A1%3A"2"%3B%7D
```

The string that gets passed on the new server:

```
months=a%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A1%3A%5C"2%5C"%3B%7D
```

The data is collected from the get with:

```
$months = $_GET['months'];
$dates = unserialize(urldecode($months));
```

The data is added to the form as a hidden field using this variable:

```
$dateserial = htmlspecialchars(serialize($dates));
```

Comment: To avoid problems with URL decoding, use base64_encode and base64_decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled in `php.ini` on the new server and "magically" escaping quotes with a `\` which is translated into `%5C` by `urlencode`.

So turn it off.

Comment: And since magic_quotes_gpc has gone the way of the dodo, you should turn it off if at all possible.